# Where can I camp for free in, or near, Byron Bay, Australia?

Tags: budget, legal, australia, tips-and-tricks, camping

I'm currently road tripping across the Gold Coast. I find myself in Byron Bay, NSW, Australia and am looking for accommodation. I rented a small camper van and don't really wish to pay 70+ Australian Dollars for a camping spot in a caravan park.

I understand that free camping is likely to get me fined something around 1000AUD, but I'm pretty sure there must be a way to free camp without bothering anyone and without getting fined.

Is there anywhere I can camp for free in, or near, Byron Bay?

Comment: In? Or nearish? (Latter seems a lot more likely than the former!)

Comment: @Gagravarr I know camping is forbidden in Byron Bay county and the fine is 1000 aud. But I'm pretty sure there must be a way to free camp without bothering anyone and without getting fined. So I'm OK with both in and around Byron. Basically I'm looking for tips.

Answer (score 12):

Camping in streets, parks and reserves in Byron Shire is prohibited.

We ask that our visitors stay in approved holiday park, camping ground or other visitor accommodation.

There are 15 legal camp grounds in the Byron Shire and information about their locations is widely available online.

Council have enforcement patrols working seven days a week targeting this issue.

The fines for illegal camping range from an on-the-spot fine of $110 to a maximum of $2,200.

A number of approved paid camping sites exist within Byron Shire and their details are easily accessible online.

If you are passing through and looking for a highway rest stop please refer to the link below....

https://secure.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/using-roads/trip-information/rest-areas/map/

Answer (score 9):

Although camping in Byron Bay and surrounding suburban areas is not permitted, if you head north of Byron Bay along the Pacific highway there are numerous free parking spots.

One of them is the Yelgun rest area. There is also one about 5 minutes north of the Byron turn off. If you go further north, you can also find the Sleepy Hollow rest area even further north but still south of the border.

If not flooded (it floods periodically), Stotts Island (about 4 km south of Chinderah) *was* also free, legal, relatively quiet, and picturesque, but [it's no longer an option](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-11-22/camping-ban-for-bruce-chick-park/6962380).

If it's an option, I would recommend trying to meet some locals who may be able to let you stay with them. This is particularly effective, as they will also know sites to see in the area.

https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/australasia-pacific-australia-new-zealand-antarctica/australia/cheap-free-camping-in-area-around-byron-bay?page=1#post_15700653
http://forums.kombiclub.com/threads/free-camping-byron-area.9934/

Comment: Is there anything south of Byron Bay.

Comment: Update 22/02/2019 You can not stay anymore overnight at Stotts island so find another place if you are like want to do free camping

Comment: @user92592 thanks for the info. Please suggest an edit to this answer and update it.

Comment: @user92592 sorry, I rejected your edit since the comments don't show up when reviewing.